# Solving equation with under and above right arrow

Tags: equations, math-operators

How can I write my equation this way and size:[image]

I could not find something like this arrows that can be written above and under I've tried \underrightarrow but it's not what I need. also having issues to write the whole equation in the shown way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not good at aligning something, but a bit hardcoding and looks close to Your example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,
top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\undlr}[1]{\underrightarrow{{\rule[-4pt]{0pt}{2pt}{#1}}}}
\begin{document}


\begin{minipage}[m]{0.2\linewidth}
\begin{align*}
&c_1-c_2- c_3 &&= -1\\
&c_1+c_2&      &=\hspace{.275cm} 1\\
&c_1    &+ c_2 &=\hspace{.275cm}1
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
% \hfill
\hspace{-0.5cm}
\begin{scriptsize}
\begin{minipage}[m]{0.2\linewidth}
\begin{align*}
&-\undlr{\rho_1+\rho_2}\hspace{0.3cm} (1/\undlr{2)\rho_2+}\rho_3\\ 
&-\rho_1+\rho_3
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{scriptsize}
% \hfill
\hspace{-0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[m]{0.2\linewidth}
\begin{align*}
c_1- &c_2  -  &c_3 &= -1\\
2&c_2 + &c_3 &= \hspace{.275cm}2\\
&  & (3/2)c_3 &= \hspace{.275cm}1
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Here's what about the arrows:(will edit in a minute)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\overleftarrow{(\alpha+\beta)}\]
\[\overrightarrow{(\eta-\epsilon)}\]
\[\overleftrightarrow{(\mu+\zeta)}\]

\[\underleftarrow{(\alpha+\beta)}\]
\[\underrightarrow{(\eta-\epsilon)}\]
\[\underleftrightarrow{(\mu+\zeta)}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: yeah i saw it but it's not what i want:(

Comment: @parsap1378 edited answer

Comment: @egreg yes, yes sorry  copied from ld example

Answer (score 2):

You can use `systeme` and `\xrightarrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,systeme}

\begin{document}

\[
\sysdelim{.}{.}
\sysalign{r,r}
\systeme{
  c_1-c_2-c_3=-1,
  c_1+c_2    = 1,
  c_1+    c_3= 1
}
\xrightarrow[-\rho_1+\rho_3]{-\rho_1+\rho_2}
{}
\xrightarrow{(-1/2)\rho_2+\rho_3}
\systeme{
  c_1-c_2-c_3=-1,
     2c_2+c_3= 2,
     (3/2)c_3=1
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,systeme}

\begin{document}

\[
\sysdelim{.}{.}
\sysalign{r,r}
\systeme{
  c_1-c_2-c_3=-1,
  c_1+c_2    = 1,
  c_1+    c_3= 1
}
\xrightarrow{
  \begin{smallmatrix}
  -\rho_1+\rho_3 \\
  -\rho_1+\rho_2 \\
  (-1/2)\rho_2+\rho_3
  \end{smallmatrix}
}
\systeme{
  c_1-c_2-c_3=-1,
     2c_2+c_3= 2,
     (3/2)c_3=1
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,systeme}

\begin{document}

\[
\sysdelim{.}{.}
\sysalign{r,r}
\systeme{
  c_1-c_2-c_3=-1,
  c_1+c_2    = 1,
  c_1+    c_3= 1
}
\begin{array}{c}
\xrightarrow{
  \begin{smallmatrix}
  -\rho_1+\rho_3 \\
  -\rho_1+\rho_2 \\
  (-1/2)\rho_2+\rho_3
  \end{smallmatrix}
}
\end{array}
\systeme{
  c_1-c_2-c_3=-1,
     2c_2+c_3= 2,
     (3/2)c_3=1
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the first code block, what is the purpose of the empty curly braces (i.e., the `{}`) in between the two arrows? Does it provide sensible horizontal spacing or something like that?

Comment: @ChrisWatson Without `{}` there wouldn’t be space between the two arrows